# Nested Dictionaries updating simultaneously Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm not sure what my problem is but it seems quite simple although I can't seem to figure it out.  I have a nested dictionary:

```
letters = [' ', '!', '"', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '|', '}', '~']

count1 = 0
lettersdict = [{i : 1 for i in letters}]*len(letters)
nestedletters = {letters[i] : lettersdict[i] for i in range(len(letters)) }
```

... (here `mapdict` is just a dictionary that maps a word in `txtmatrix2[x]` to a word in `trainingset[count]` and I iterate through all `txtmatrix[x]`'s and their corresponding `trainingset[count]`)

```
for key in mapdict:
if len(txtmatrix[x][key]) == len(trainingset[count][mapdict[key]]):
    for letnum in range(len(txtmatrix2[x][key])):
        letter = txtmatrix2[x][key][letnum]
        corespletter = trainingset[count][mapdict[key]][letnum]
        if letter in letters:
            nestedletters[letter][corespletter] += 2
            sums[mapofletters[letter]] += 2
```

The problem is that when I run the code I want it to count the number of times a letter that appears in my object character recognition (`txtmatrix2`) as for example 'a' appears in my gold standard(`trainingset` as 'a','b','c'...).  However when I run this code, it seems as if instead of updating the dictionary associated with `nestedletters['a']['a']` it updates `nestedletters[j for j in letters]['a']` (ie it updates the 'a' slot for all dictionaries corresponding to 'a'...'Z').  Curious if someone has any ideas with what is going on.

Cameron

Comment: Each dictionary in `lettersdict = [{i : 1 for i in letters}]*len(letters)` is essentially the same object

Comment: I know duplicate says _list if lists_, but it's really about _list of something mutable_ and using multiplication on said list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the duplicate and pointing out immutability of the dictionary I wrote.  Updated code and fixed it